# How can I update the content of a tab in an ExtJS TabPanel?

Tags: javascript, extjs, tabpanel

I have a tab panel like this:

```
var tab1 = {
    id: 'section1',
    title: 'First Section',
    padding: 10,
    html: '(this content will be replaced with an ajax load)'
}

var tab2 = {
    id: 'section2',
    title: 'Second Section',
    padding: 10,
    html: '(this content will be replaced with an ajax load)'
}

var tab3 = {
    id: 'section3',
    title: 'Third Section',
    padding: 10,
    html: '(this content will be replaced with an ajax load)'
}

var modules_info_panel = new Ext.TabPanel({
    region: 'center',
    activeTab: 0,
    border: false,
    defaults:{autoScroll:true},
    items:[tab1, tab2, tab3]
});
```

Then after creating this tabpanel, I would like to dynamically change the content of the tabs, but none of these work:

```
tab1.html = 'new html'; // no effect
tab1.title = 'new title'; // no effect
tab1.update('new text'); // error: tab1.update is not a function
viewport.doLayout(); // no effect
```

Since I want to load the contents of each of the tabs via **AJAX**, I don't want to **add** tabs dynamically [as suggested in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876292/ext-js-dynamically-changing-content-of-tab-in-a-tabpanel) but want the tabs to be **visible from the first load** and each tab's content to be **changed** dynamically when clicked.

How can I change the content of a tab after it has been created?

**Update:**

Thanks @Chau for catching my oversight: when I create the tabs with `Ext.Panel` instead of simple javascript object literals, then it works:

```
var tab1 = new Ext.Panel ({
    id: 'section1',
    title: 'First Section',
    padding: 10,
    html: '(this content will be replaced with an ajax load)'
});

var tab2 = new Ext.Panel ({
    id: 'section2',
    title: 'Second Section',
    padding: 10,
    html: '(this content will be replaced with an ajax load)'
});

var tab3 = new Ext.Panel ({
    id: 'section3',
    title: 'Third Section',
    padding: 10,
    html: '(this content will be replaced with an ajax load)'
});

var modules_info_panel = new Ext.TabPanel({
    region: 'center',
    activeTab: 0,
    border: false,
    defaults:{autoScroll:true},
    items:[tab1, tab2, tab3]
});

tab1.update('new content with update'); //works
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you create `tab1` it is an object with 4 properties. When you add `tab1` as an *item* to your tab panel, the tab panels initializer will create a tab based on the properties from `tab1`. Your `tab1` is still however an object with 4 properties and not a reference to the tab created by your tab panel.

I would create a `panel` with your 4 properties and add that panel as a child in the tab panel.

```
var tab1 = new Ext.Panel({
    id: 'section1',
    title: 'First Section',
    padding: 10,
    html: '(this content will be replaced with an ajax load)'
});
```

Then the tab panel should use your panel instead of creating its own panel.

I haven't tested this code, but I hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

`modules_info_panel.get(0)` will return first tab object (by default Ext.Panel instance) so:

```
 modules_info_panel.get(0).setTitle('new title');
```

will set new title